# Total derivative and constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I'm trying to calculate the total derivative of functions that have constants. For example, I know that if I calculate the total derivative of $\chi e^{\phi}$, using

```
Dt[χ*E^φ]
```

I get:

```
E^φ χ Dt[χ] + E^φ Dt[χ]
```

(in latex code is $e^{\phi} \chi Dt[\phi] + e^{\phi} Dt[\chi]$). I'm interested in applying it to cases where there is a constant and still having the `Dt[ ]`. For example, when I want to calculate the total derivative of $K \chi e^{\phi} $ where $K$ is a constant, it is

```
Dt[B*χ*E^φ, Constants -> B]
B E^φ χ Dt[φ], Constants -> {B}] + B E^φ Dt[χ, Constants -> {B}]
```

However, I would like to obtain Dt[\phi] without "Constants -> {B}" since when applying it in more complex expressions, I could factor $Dt[φ]$ in terms that do not have B but not here because it contains the constant $B$ information. Could anyone guide me or give me any suggestions? Maybe it's simpler than I think

Comment: btw, your code uses `Dt[f, Constants -> {B}]` which does not work. it should be `Dt[f,x, Constants -> {B}`  if you look at help you see the option `Constants` only works when you have also supplied an `x` in second argument?

Comment: You could do `SetAttributes[B, Constant]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you just set `Dt[a]` to zero?

```
Dt[a x y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dt[a x y] /. Dt[a] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ad if you are using the version with `Dt[f,x,Constants->{a}]` you then use `Dt[a,x] -> 0` instead.